# How do I mock a contract when testing using Hardhat?

Tags: mocking, solidity, hardhat

I'm trying every solution I find online but I still can't figure it out.

I have two contracts and I'm trying to write some tests for one of them, let's just call them `ContractA` and `ContractM` (M for Mock). I'm now writing tests for `ContractA` and I need to mock a single function from `ContractM`.

I've also tried using the `deployMockContract()` function explained in the [Waffle Documentation](https://ethereum-waffle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mock-contract.html) but I have no idea how to get the ABI of my contract. Every example I've found does `import IERC20 from "../build/IERC20.json"` but these use cases differ much from mine as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the [smock](https://github.com/defi-wonderland/smock) hardhat contracts mocking library.

Comment: smock is so good, unfortunately it's limited to ethers v5 has it use @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle, if you know a way to mock a contract in ethers v6 or viem, without writing test smart contract that is, that'd be awesome